# Private Messages Notification in Community Site Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, chatter

I am trying to show some notification for unread private message in a VF page of Community Site.
In standard chatter page it used to notify the number of unread mails side by Messages link.

I did some search regarding this but didn't get clear idea how to achieve this.
Please suggest some ideas how I can know that a user has some unread private messages or how I can show similar functionality as of standard chatter page in VF page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all possible with the [`ConnectApi`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_connect_api.htm):

> The ConnectApi namespace (also called Chatter in Apex) provides
>   classes for accessing the same data available in Chatter REST API. Use
>   Chatter in Apex to create custom Chatter experiences in Salesforce.

specifically with the [`ChatterMessages`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterMessages_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterMessages_static_methods) class.

> Access and modify message and conversation data.

You can call [`getUnreadCount()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterMessages_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterMessages_getUnreadCount) which will

> Returns the number of conversations the context user has marked
>   unread. If the number is less than 50, it will return the exact
>   unreadCount, and hasMore = false. If the context user has more than
>   50, unreadCount = 50 and hasMore = true.

However, your best bet is probably the overloaded method [`getUnreadCount(String communityId)`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterMessages_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterMessages_getUnreadCount_2) which

> Returns the number of conversations the context user has marked unread
>   across their available communities. If the number is less than 50, it
>   will return the exact unreadCount, and hasMore = false. If the context
>   user has more than 50, unreadCount = 50 and hasMore = true.

Either way, the methods will return an instance of [`ConnectApi.UnreadConversationCount`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/connectAPI_outputs.htm#capi_UnreadMessageCount_output) which you can use to then get the `unreadCount`, the number of unread messages.

---

Your final code snippet would look like:

```
ConnectApi.UnreadConversationCount unreadMessageCount = ConnectApi.ChatterMessages.getUnreadCount('communityId');
Integer numberOfUnreadMessages = unreadMessageCount.unreadCount;
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse for your suggestion.I tried the same and now I am able to get the unread count of private messages.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following line of code in your apex controller:

```
ConnectApi.ChatterMessages.getUnreadCount()
```

> Returns the number of conversations the context user has marked unread. If the number is less than 50, it will return the exact unreadCount, and hasMore = false. If the context user has more than 50, unreadCount = 50 and hasMore = true.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterMessages_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterMessages_getUnreadCount

Comment: Thanks Christian for your suggestion.Its really helped me.